# Help running a jar from within a java program using JarClassLoader

Tags: java, jvm

I'm trying to run a jar within a java program and capture its stdout. **I want to do this to avoid the JVM startup cost every time the jar is run.** What is the simplest way to do this?

I started by modifying Java's JarClassLoader and adding a SecurityManager subclass to that to prevent system exits. The JarClassLoader is a subclass of URLClassLoader, and looks up the main class in the jar and then executes the main function there. But now I'm getting InvocationTargetExceptions when I try to execute that function even though I'm passing the correct arguments. Anyone with an idea of where to go from here?

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: I'm guessing the error is due to the security you set up, have you a stack trace?  Is the jar a third party app?  Is it not possible to write wrapper rather than use the main method directly.

Comment: You could use aspectj to apply short circuit "around advice" to code that calls System.exit to prevent it from being executed.

Comment: Are just executing a main() method or are you using a common interface for executing "plugins"? Do the dynamically loaded jar files have dependencies to additional libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use `Runtime.exec()`, but then I couldn't prevent `System.exit()`.